# Why can't you define a materialized view using bound parameters in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I've tracked where the error message comes from in the source:

```
    /*
     * A materialized view would either need to save parameters for use in
     * maintaining/loading the data or prohibit them entirely.  The latter
     * seems safer and more sane.
     */
    if (query_contains_extern_params(query))
        ereport(ERROR,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED),
                 errmsg("materialized views may not be defined using bound parameters")));
```

Permalink: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ef3109500030030b0e8d3c1d7f2b409d702cc49a/src/backend/parser/analyze.c#L2538)

Why is this? Why would a materialized view need to save parameters?

I'm using Elixir and I can't create the view from Ecto using:

```
Repo.query("CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW $1 AS
        SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE
          resource_type = $2 AND
          task_type = $3
      ", [view_name, resource_type, task_type])
```

but

```
Repo.query("CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW \"#{view_name}\" AS
        SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE
          resource_type = '#{resource_type}' AND
          task_type = '#{task_type}'
      ", [])
```

works fine.

Please tell me what I'm missing, if you can.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case you are using a prepared SQL statement with placeholders and you provide the values to fill those placeholders separately. Materialized view would require to store those values to be able to rerun the query.

In the second case you construct a query string yourself inside your programming language, by injecting values into the string. And then you pass the query as a string, without placeholders and values to the PostgreSQL. In this case materialized view can just store the string and this is it. And is able to rerun the query.

The problem with the second case is that you might allow [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to happen in your query.